# python SQL query insert shows empty rows

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to do a insert query in the SQL. It indicates that it succeed but shows no record in the database. Here's my code

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost",self.user,"",self.db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
id_val = 123456;
path_val = "/homes/error.path"
host_val = "123.23.45.64"
time_val = 7
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO success (id,path,hostname,time_elapsed) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (id_val, path_val,host_val,time_val))

print "query executed"
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print rows
```

this outputs the following

```
query executed
()
```

it gives me no errors but the database seems to be empty. I tried my SQL query in the mysql console. executed the following command.

```
INSERT INTO success (id,path,hostname,time_elapsed)
VALUES (1,'sometext','hosttext',4);
```

This works fine as I can see the database got populated.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM success LIMIT 5;
+----+----------+----------+--------------+
| id | path     | hostname | time_elapsed |
+----+----------+----------+--------------+
|  1 | sometext | hosttext |            4 |
+----+----------+----------+--------------+
```

so I am guessing the SQL query command is right. Not sure why my `cursor.execute` is not responding. Could someone please point me to the right direction. Can't seem to figure out the bug. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you are sending your INSERT record, you should commit your changes in the database:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO success (id,path,hostname,time_elapsed) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (id_val, path_val,host_val,time_val))
conn.commit()
```

When you want to read the data, you should first send your query as you did through your interpreter.

So before you fetch the data, execute the SELECT command:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM success")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print rows
```

If you want to do it pythonic:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM success")
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```